# Page view printed in a block

Tags: views

I have created a page view, and I want to put in a block. I am not looking for a block view.

Comment: Why can't you use a block view?  Unless you are more specific, it will be difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I have to use Page View coz I want to add search to it and if i use block view i do not get to add a search field. Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed) does not work in block view, i have created in applied in block view but the exposed box does not appear in block view and so i am using page view.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.  Although it will require some learning, you can use the Panels module to "override" the way nodes are displayed (you can choose from all nodes or overriding specific content types, specific user roles, etc.)

Using this approach, you can make a "page" view display as a block.  In fact, with Panels, you can basically use any content in Drupal as a  "block."  This power does come with some complexity but it should allow you to do what you want with some experimenting.